# How do I correctly use ListView array adapter to display data from a Firebase database in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-listview

How can I fetch data from a Firebase database and display it in a ListView while using an array adapter? I am getting an error when using array adapter. Here's the error message:

"None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

(Context, Int, Array<(out) T!>)

where T cannot be inferred for    constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, objects: Array<(out) T!>) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter

(Context, Int, Int)   where T cannot be inferred for    constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, textViewResourceId: Int) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter

(Context, Int, (Mutable)List<T!>)   where T cannot be inferred for    constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, objects: (Mutable)List<T!>) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter"

I've got to say that I'm new to Kotlin and Java.

```
                //Code in here is run when Firebase DB connection is successful
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    //
                    for(oneRecord in snapshot.children){
                        val taskListview = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.taskListview)
                        var tasksListViewer = oneRecord.child("task").getValue(String::class.java)
                        val arrayAdapter = **ArrayAdapter**(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tasksListViewer)
                        taskListview.adapter = arrayAdapter
                    }
                }
            }
```

The phrase ArrayAdapter (in bold) in the line `val arrayAdapter = **ArrayAdapter**(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tasksListViewer)` is the cause of the error.

Comment: What's the exact and complete error message?

Comment: A ListView is not a TextView, so it doesn't make sense to call `setText` on it. Also, your data is not a single String or CharSequence, so you would not be able to pass it as a String anyway. Read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#AdapterViews

Comment: I have decided not to use ListView with setText as @Tenfour04 advised - it makes sense that way. Thanks guys.